# Config file - help in trying to get it to work with paths and Mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, config, mouseover

I'm having an issue trying to get my Windows Forms app to work with a config file, I've read a quite few posts here and elsewhere but I'm still unable to figure out how to get it to work, hence my question here, I'm working on my first app. I've added the Configuration.Manager .dll to my project. I'm also trying to get a MouseHover working via the config file path.

The config file reads thus

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Google" value="http://www.google.com/"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Previous Path String in app

```
//public static string Google = @"http://www.google.com/";
```

The first line below worked fine.

```
//System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Google);
```

But this I cannot get to work at all, I've tried various examples.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]);
```

Code together

```
private void GoogleW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Google);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
 }
```

Same with the mouse over, it works with

```
//ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.GoogleW, @Google);
```

But not with this, I couldn't find anything stating you could use a config file for Mouse over text.

```
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.GoogleW, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]));
```

Code Together

```
private void GoogleW_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
  //ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.GoogleW, @Google);
  ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.GoogleW, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]));
```

Comment: you have multiple spellings of explorer.exe (exploror.exe) above - also I presume you really mean iexplore.exe

Comment: An empty Try-Catch isn't helping you see what is happening in your code.  You have to describe what "not working" means.  Make sure your events are wired up.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks for your reply, I do have some filled Try-Catch blocks elsewhere in the app, sloppy programing on my behalf not uploading the complete code here...

Comment: @ajg spelling mistakes are due to typing in code at 1.30am... The code above I changed to link to Google as my app actually points to a work location. UNC paths I had explorer.exe opening, and yes iexplore.exe probably for Web links, but I'll leave that out so the users default browser opens the page.

Comment: @LarsTech the error I'm getting is - Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided... So it seems the key in the config file isn't being picked up. <add key="Google" value="http://www.google.com/"/>; Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]);

Comment: Use your debugger to see what the value is that you are getting from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]`.  Sounds like you are getting an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `http://www.google.com/` in your `web.config` file instead of `www.google.com/`?

**Update:** also as mentioned above by @ajg it's `explorer.exe` not `exploror.exe`

Comment: Thanks I'll try the full path in the (app.config) file. Spelling mistakes sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to specify the name of the process, unless you specifically need to open Internet Explorer, and not the system's default web browser. I personally hate when programs force open Internet Explorer, and not my default browser.

```
Process.Start(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]);
```

Comment: Agreed "I personally hate when programs force open Internet Explorer, and not my default browser." I'll be leaving the code browser specific free.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!

App.config file

```
<add key="Google"  value="http://www.google.com/" />
```

Code

```
private void GoogleS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]);
                string GoogleS = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"];
                Process.Start(GoogleS);
            }
            catch (Exception GoogleErr)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(GoogleErr.Message);
            }
        }

        private void GoogleS_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.GoogleS, (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Google"]));
        }
```